# Convert a specific text string into a specific number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-conversion

Is it possible to convert a specific text string into a specific number in Excel using formula?

For instance, I have three different strings in column as values: `banana`, `apple` and `apricot`. Now I want to change all of the occurrences of those strings to numbers. `banana` to 0, `apple` to 1 and `apricot` to 2. How could I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: There are various ways. What have you tried?

Comment: @SJR, I tried to do it manually. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table of the strings and their ouput:

[image]

Then use VLOOKUP to return the correct number:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,G:H,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

---

Another method, hard code the table in the formula.  This method uses MATCH as your output is serial numbers.

```
=MATCH(A1,{"Banana","Apple","Apricot"},0)-1
```

This will return the `0`,`1`,`2`

But if you want a different outcome, not so serial, then place the outputs in CHOOSE:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{"Banana","Apple","Apricot"},0),0,1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert **in place**, you cannot use a formula.  Before:

[image]

the code:

```
Sub qwerty()
    With Range("A:A")
        .Replace What:="banana", replacement:=0
        .Replace What:="apple", replacement:=1
        .Replace What:="apricot", replacement:=2
    End With
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building a lookup table with 2 columns (your strings and your integers). Than simply use INDEX and MATCH function.